# When an iOS native page is pushed to a Flutter page, the Flutter page undergoes changes, with the font becoming bolder

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

It displays correctly in the iOS simulator, but there are issues when displayed on a real device.

```
let flutterVc = FlutterViewController(project: nil, initialRoute: "forgot_password", nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(flutterVc, animated: true)
}
```

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter_module/pages/routes.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> globalNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

void main() {
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: const Size(393, 852),
      builder: (_, child) {
        return MaterialApp(
          color: Colors.white,
          navigatorKey: globalNavigatorKey,
          title: 'Driver App',
          initialRoute: 'forgot_password',
          routes: routes,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Screenshot 1][image: Screenshot 2]

Has anyone encountered this issue, and how was it resolved?

I've tried many pages, and they all become distorted.